# Backing up databases and images from my VPS to Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, backup

I have my own VPS running Windows Server 2012 and MSSQL 2012 Express.

2 requirements I have:

1. I want to backup all databases to Azure
2. I want to backup images that were uploaded to the websites that are running on this VPS. Now instead of just copying ALL images (~ 15GB and growing) every day, I want to only backup **new** or **changed** images.

Are these 2 scenarios possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I'd recommend you take a look at the SQL Server backup to Microsoft Azure tool: http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=40740.
2. You should look at using Azure Backp for this scenario: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/backup/.  Effectively install a backup agent locally and it will manage backups based on configuration (i.e. doing just delta backups).